# Spark sql filter unpredictable behavior

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Spark sql filter is producing inconsistent and random results, not scanning entire orc file.

Data in the orc file is huge and split across 50 partitions.

```
root
 |-- ProductID: string (nullable = true)
 |-- ProductName: string (nullable = true)
```

Data
| ProductID | ProductName |
|-----------|-------------|
| 1         | A1          |
| 1         | A2          |
| 1         | A3          |
| 2         | A1          |
| 2         | A3          |
| 3         | A1          |
| 3         | A2          |
| 4         | A3          |
| 4         | A1          |
| 5         | A3          |

Loaded the orc file to data frame.

```
val df = spark.read.orc("/src/resources/products/")

df.createOrReplaceTempView("products")

val sqlDF=spark.sql(select * from products where ProductName ='A1')
```

Expected results:
| ProductID | ProductName |
|-----------|-------------|
| 1         | A1          |
| 2         | A1          |
| 3         | A1          |
| 4         | A1          |

But result is random and inconsistent as below and not providing correct result anytime.

First run:
| ProductID | ProductName |
|-----------|-------------|
| 1         | A1          |
| 4         | A1          |

Second run:
| ProductID | ProductName |
|-----------|-------------|
| 1         | A1          |
| 3         | A1          |

Tired the above multiple times but not getting expected results

Comment: Are you using limit 2 or show(2) on the final DF in your code?

Comment: Please show the full code you're using to display these results.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Most likely your ORC file has multiple records that have the same ProductName value. There is no ORDER BY clause in your SQL statement, so any could be returned as the first result--it is not guaranteed to be deterministic. It's hard to tell without seeing the full code, but to get the expected behavior, you may need to order or aggregate your results.

Answer (score 0):

For filtering in scala use

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col

val filteredDF = df.filter(col("ProductName") === "A1")
```

For filtering in PySpark use

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

filtered_df = df.filter(col("ProductName") == "A1")
```